# Turn off Redis for testing in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, configuration, redis

I want to turn off Redis, when I testing.

Now I'm stuck here:
Change `phpunit.xml` like this `<env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>`
In my controller I have this string `RedisListener::setupConnection('production');`

And the last one is RedistListener:

```
  class RedisListener
  {
     public static function setupConnection() {

       if (env('APP_ENV') != 'testing') {

         return config(['database.redis.default.host' => 'false']); //Don't know what I should write here
       }
     }
  }
```

I can change some values in config, but it's doesn't help, obviously)
What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

If you want do change redis host while testing use `<env name="REDIS_HOST" value="0"/>` in phpunit.xml.

If you you want to run unit test on separate database I would suggesting you configuring inmemory sqlite

config/database.php

```
    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => ':memory:',
        'prefix' => '',
    ]
```

and change the db connection in phpunit.xml to `<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>`

then do not forget to use DatabaseMigrations trait in your tests